# How do you pass a callback function to a sibling component in React

Tags: reactjs, callback, state

How do you pass a callback function to a sibling component such that a button in one can trigger an action in the another? The following code is an example of an attempt I made that ended up infinitely resetting the state in Index.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

const ComplexComponent = ({setCallbackFunction}) => {
    setCallbackFunction(() => console.log("hello world"))
    return <div/>
}

const Button = ({onClick}) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={onClick}>
            Submit
        </button>
    )
}

export default function Index() {
    const [callbackFunction, setCallbackFunction] = useState(() => {})

    // EXPECTED: callbackFunction should log "hello world" after clicking Button
    // ACTUAL: state is reset infinitely

    return (
        <>
            <ComplexComponent setCallbackFunction={setCallbackFunction} />
            <Button onClick={callbackFunction}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case function is getting executed as soon as you initialize. example below, the function is not returning anything. its just printing **initial** immediately. Since its not returning anything, *undefined* will be set to **callbackFunction** variable.

```
const [callbackFunction, setCallbackFunction] = React.useState(() =>
    console.log('initial')
  );
```

solution:
wrap the function with another function. so that, the outer function returns inner function instead of undefined

```
const [callbackFunction, setCallbackFunction] = React.useState(
    () => () => console.log('initial')
  );
```

now you can reset call back function, again with a wrapper function. without the wrapper same thing here as before. function will get executed immediately and print **hello world**

```
const ComplexComponent = ({ setCallbackFunction }) => {
  setCallbackFunction(() => () => console.log('hello world'));
  return <div />;
};
```

to avoid different component render error consider useEffect.

```
const ComplexComponent = ({ setCallbackFunction }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setCallbackFunction(() => () => console.log('hello world'));
  }, []);

  return <div />;
};
```